# Как сделать перенос данных из одной БД в другую на лету?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, администрирование

Есть задача:
**PostgreSQL 9.6.6**
Для тестирования и выявления неисправностей после обращения пользователей копировать актуальные данные в тестовую базу и проводить работы с ней пока не найдется решение. Но нужно копировать так что бы пользователи в этот момент продолжали работать и не почувствовали что с базой что то делают.

Помогите решить данную задачку.

Comment: обычный pg_dump. но конечно его присутствие заметят, время ответа БД возрастет в связи с сильной загрузкой дисков